# Is there a other way to Group or Merge a separated Collection of List<T> and store the List<T> to the index of new List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a comparison table in gridview using ASP.NET and C#. I'm rendering it data on each table cell or per row. Is there other way that can group or merge the 3 or more list into a single list?

So, far I use the .Concat method extensions but it just add to the collection instead to insert to index of the list.

```
var input = new List<InventoryItem>();

for (var i = 0; i < inventoryItems.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        var list = inventoryItems[0].Concat(inventoryItems[i]);
    }
}

for (var day = 0; day <= 31; day++)
{
    // Loop the Output by Day Index

    if (day != 0)
    {
        var label = new Label();
        label.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

        e.Row.Cells[day].Controls.Add(label);
    }
}

public class InventoryItem 
{
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public Name string {get;set;}
    public Price decimal {get;set}
    public Description string {get;set}
}
```

Sample Data:

```
[JANUARY]
inventoryItems - Count = 3
    [0] - Count = 31
        [1] 
            - Date: {1/1/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [2]
            - Date: {1/2/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [3]
            - Date: {1/3/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [4]
            - Date: {1/4/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [5]
            - Date: {1/5/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [6]
            - Date: {1/6/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [7]
            - Date: {1/7/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [8]
            - Date: {1/8/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [9]
            - Date: {1/9/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [10]
            - Date: {1/10/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [11]
            - Date: {1/11/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [12]
            - Date: {1/12/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [13]
            - Date: {1/13/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [14]
            - Date: {1/14/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [15]
            - Date: {1/15/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [16]
            - Date: {1/16/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [17]
            - Date: {1/17/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [18]
            - Date: {1/18/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [19]
            - Date: {1/19/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [20]
            - Date: {1/20/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [21]
            - Date: {1/21/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [22]
            - Date: {1/22/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [23]
            - Date: {1/23/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [24]    
            - Date: {1/24/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [25]
            - Date: {1/25/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [26]
            - Date: {1/26/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [27]
            - Date: {1/27/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [28]
            - Date: {1/28/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [29]
            - Date: {1/29/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [30]
            - Date: {1/30/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [31]
            - Date: {1/31/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"

    [1] - Count = 31
        [1] 
            - Date: {1/1/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [2]
            - Date: {1/2/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [3]
            - Date: {1/3/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [4]
            - Date: {1/4/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [5]
            - Date: {1/5/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [6]
            - Date: {1/6/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [7]
            - Date: {1/7/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [8]
            - Date: {1/8/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [9]
            - Date: {1/9/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [10]
            - Date: {1/10/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [11]
            - Date: {1/11/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [12]
            - Date: {1/12/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [13]
            - Date: {1/13/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [14]
            - Date: {1/14/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [15]
            - Date: {1/15/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [16]
            - Date: {1/16/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [17]
            - Date: {1/17/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [18]
            - Date: {1/18/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [19]
            - Date: {1/19/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [20]
            - Date: {1/20/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [21]
            - Date: {1/21/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [22]
            - Date: {1/22/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [23]
            - Date: {1/23/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [24]    
            - Date: {1/24/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [25]
            - Date: {1/25/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [26]
            - Date: {1/26/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [27]
            - Date: {1/27/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [28]
            - Date: {1/28/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [29]
            - Date: {1/29/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [30]
            - Date: {1/30/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [31]
            - Date: {1/31/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"

    [2] - Count = 31
        [1] 
            - Date: {1/1/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [2]
            - Date: {1/2/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [3]
            - Date: {1/3/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [4]
            - Date: {1/4/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [5]
            - Date: {1/5/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [6]
            - Date: {1/6/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [7]
            - Date: {1/7/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [8]
            - Date: {1/8/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [9]
            - Date: {1/9/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [10]
            - Date: {1/10/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [11]
            - Date: {1/11/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [12]
            - Date: {1/12/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [13]
            - Date: {1/13/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [14]
            - Date: {1/14/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [15]
            - Date: {1/15/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [16]
            - Date: {1/16/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [17]
            - Date: {1/17/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [18]
            - Date: {1/18/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [19]
            - Date: {1/19/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [20]
            - Date: {1/20/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [21]
            - Date: {1/21/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [22]
            - Date: {1/22/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [23]
            - Date: {1/23/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [24]    
            - Date: {1/24/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [25]
            - Date: {1/25/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [26]
            - Date: {1/26/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [27]
            - Date: {1/27/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [28]
            - Date: {1/28/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [29]
            - Date: {1/29/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [30]
            - Date: {1/30/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"
        [31]
            - Date: {1/31/2019}
            - Name: "Salad"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Salad Description"

[FEBRUARY]
inventoryItems - Count = 3
    [0] - Count = 28
        [1] 
            - Date: {2/1/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [2]
            - Date: {2/2/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [3]
            - Date: {2/3/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [4]
            - Date: {2/4/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [5]
            - Date: {2/5/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [6]
            - Date: {2/6/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [7]
            - Date: {2/7/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [8]
            - Date: {2/8/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [9]
            - Date: {2/9/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [10]
            - Date: {2/10/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [11]
            - Date: {2/11/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [12]
            - Date: {2/12/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [13]
            - Date: {2/13/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [14]
            - Date: {2/14/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [15]
            - Date: {2/15/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [16]
            - Date: {2/16/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [17]
            - Date: {2/17/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [18]
            - Date: {2/18/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [19]
            - Date: {2/19/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [20]
            - Date: {2/20/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [21]
            - Date: {2/21/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [22]
            - Date: {2/22/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [23]
            - Date: {2/23/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [24]    
            - Date: {2/24/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [25]
            - Date: {2/25/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [26]
            - Date: {2/26/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [27]
            - Date: {2/27/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [28]
            - Date: {2/28/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"

    [1] - Count = 28    
        [1] 
            - Date: {2/1/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [2]
            - Date: {2/2/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [3]
            - Date: {2/3/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [4]
            - Date: {2/4/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [5]
            - Date: {2/5/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [6]
            - Date: {2/6/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [7]
            - Date: {2/7/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [8]
            - Date: {2/8/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [9]
            - Date: {2/9/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [10]
            - Date: {2/10/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [11]
            - Date: {2/11/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [12]
            - Date: {2/12/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [13]
            - Date: {2/13/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [14]
            - Date: {2/14/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [15]
            - Date: {2/15/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [16]
            - Date: {2/16/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [17]
            - Date: {2/17/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [18]
            - Date: {2/18/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [19]
            - Date: {2/19/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [20]
            - Date: {2/20/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [21]
            - Date: {2/21/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [22]
            - Date: {2/22/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [23]
            - Date: {2/23/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [24]    
            - Date: {2/24/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [25]
            - Date: {2/25/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [26]
            - Date: {2/26/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [27]
            - Date: {2/27/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [28]
            - Date: {2/28/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"

    [2] - Count = 28
        [1] 
            - Date: {2/1/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [2]
            - Date: {2/2/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [3]
            - Date: {2/3/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [4]
            - Date: {2/4/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [5]
            - Date: {2/5/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [6]
            - Date: {2/6/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [7]
            - Date: {2/7/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [8]
            - Date: {2/8/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [9]
            - Date: {2/9/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [10]
            - Date: {2/10/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [11]
            - Date: {2/11/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [12]
            - Date: {2/12/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [13]
            - Date: {2/13/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [14]
            - Date: {2/14/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [15]
            - Date: {2/15/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [16]
            - Date: {2/16/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [17]
            - Date: {2/17/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [18]
            - Date: {2/18/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [19]
            - Date: {2/19/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [20]
            - Date: {2/20/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [21]
            - Date: {2/21/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [22]
            - Date: {2/22/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [23]
            - Date: {2/23/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [24]    
            - Date: {2/24/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [25]
            - Date: {2/25/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [26]
            - Date: {2/26/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [27]
            - Date: {2/27/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"
        [28]
            - Date: {2/28/2019}
            - Name: "Gelatin"
            - Price: 10.00
            - Description: "This Gelatin Description"

[TO DECEMBER]
```

I expect the ouptut of:

```
inventoryItems - Count = 31
    [0]
        [0] - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [1]
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [2] 
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
    [1]
        [0] - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [1]
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [2] 
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
    [2]
        [0] - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [1]
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [2] 
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
    [3]
        [0] - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [1]
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [2] 
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
    [4]
        [0] - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [1]
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [2] 
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
    ...
    ...
    ...
    [31]
        [0] - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [1]
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
        [2] 
            - Date
            - Name
            - Price
            - Description
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code and question what you are asking. Perhaps you want to do a list of lists? `var input = new List<List<InventoryItem>>();`

Comment: What does "to the index of" mean in the context of a `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of lists of items, where every list has the same length. Or in other words: an outer list where every element is an inner list. Every inner list has the same length.

As output you want to exchange the outer list and the inner list.

It is like a two dimensional array where you switch the indexes: so if you use X[3][2], you get element [2][3] from your original list. Something like "turning a table".

```
List<List<InventoryItem>> source = ...
List<List<InventoryItem>> swappedSource = SwapMySource(source);
InventoryItem theInventoryItemThatIWant = swappedSource[3][4];
```

### A generic and efficient solution

It would be a huge waste of processing power, to swap the complete source list if you only will be using InventoryItem [3][4]. Hence if is wise to create a class `SwappedList` that will only swap the items when they are asked for.

Let's do this generic, so you can use the SwappedList class for other types as well

If you implement `IList<List<T>>`, you'll also have to implement `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll probably also want `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

```
class SwappedList<T> : IList<IList<T>>,
      // Only if desired; most functions will be one lined calls to IList<IList<T>>
      IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<T>>
      ICollection<ICollection<T>>,
      IReadOnlyCollection<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>
      IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public IList<IList<T>> Source {get; set;}

    ... // TODO: implement
}
```

The most important function will be the swapping. If you ask for index [4][3] you need to return [3][4]:

```
public T GetSwapped(int i, int j)
{
    return this.Source[j][i];
}
public void SetSwapped(int i, int j, T value)
{
     this.Source[j][i] = value;
}
```

Consider adding a range check and throw ArgumentOutOfRange if needed.

Now to implement property `this[int index]`, you'll need to return an object that implements IList. This object should contain all swapped Source objects.

```
private class SwappedOuterList<T> : IList<T> // TODO: IReadOnlyList<T> etc?
{
    public IList<IList<T>> Source {get; set; }
    public int OuterIndex{get; set;}

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get {return this.Source.GetSwapped(this.OuterIndex, index); 
        set this.Source.SetSwapped(this.OuterIndex, index) = value;
    }
```

So now it is easy to implement the get part of `this` in `SwappedList<T>`

```
public IList<T> this [int index]
{
    get
    {
        return new SwappedOuterList<T>
        {
            Source = this.Source,
            OuterIndex = index,
        };
    }
```

Usage:

```
List<List<InventoryItem>> source = ...
var swappedSource = new SwappedSource<InventoryItem>{Source = source};    
InventoryItem x = swappedSource[3][4];
x.Name = "Hello";
```

What really happens, is that the pointer to source is copied. When you ask for `swappedSource[3]`, a new object is created: the pointer to source is copied again, as well as index 3.

The`[4]` is executed on the newly created object: this function call `GetSwapped(3, 4)`, which returns `source[4][3]`. The assignment acts only on the Name of this returned object.

See how efficient this would be: only some copying of pointers and indexes, no creation of complete lists of which only one element is used.

To implement `IList<IList<T>>` you'll need to implement some more functions. `Count` is trivial. `GetEnumerator<IList<T>>` is a bit more difficult:

```
public IEnumerator<IList<T>> GetEnumerator()
{
    // all innerArrays have the same length:
    int innerArrayLength = ...
    for (int i=0; i<innerArrayLength; ++i)
       yield return this[i];
}
```

### Back to your problem

After creation of the SwappedList class, all you have to do is create an extension function for InventoryItem. This way you can use it as if it was a LINQ function:

```
public Static IList<IList<InventoryItem>> ToSwappedLists(this List<List<InventoryItem>> source)
{
    return new SwappedList<InventoryItem>
    {
        Source = source,
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = FetchMyInventoryItems
    .Where(x => ...)
    .ToSwappedList()
    .GroupBy(...)
    .Select(...)
```

### If you are only going to use the complete lists

The above methods are only useful if you don't plan to swap complete lists. If you are certain that you will always use the complete list, don't bother creating a complete SwappedList class, only create the extension function that will create a fully swapped List:

```
public Static List<List<InventoryItem>> ToSwappedLists(this List<List<InventoryItem>> source)
{
    // TODO: check for null source
    // TODO: check if all inner lists have same size
    int innerListSize = ..

    List<List<InventoryItem> result = new List<List<InventoryItem>>(innerListSize));
    for (int y = 0; y<innerListsize; ++y)
    {
        var swappedList = this.Source.Select(x => source[x][y]).ToList();
        result.Add(swappedList);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage is the same:

```
 var result = FetchMyInventoryItems()
    .ToSwappedList();
```